# MySQL: Select all fields start with given number and next character is letter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with random varchar number/letters as such:

```
1a
101a
101b
101c
11b
14a
14b
14c
14z
108a
108b
```

and I would like to `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE VAR = [SPECIFIC NUMBER]/FOLLOWING ANY LETTER`.

For example **I am using this wrong** method where it selects everything starting with 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE var LIKE  '1%'
```

which gives me all of the above example because all start with 1.
I want this to select only: `1a`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE var REGEXP '^1[[:alnum:]]'
```

Regexp explanation:

- `^` for start of string
- `1` for your specific number
- `[[:alnum:]]` for an alfanumeric character - if you strictly want letters, use `alpha` here. e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE var REGEXP '^1[[:alpha:]]'
```

<kbd>**[Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94e9a/9)**</kbd>

Comment: This still returns everything though, I think the expression should be `'^1[a-z]'` or `'^1[:alnum:]'` a sthe OP only wants to return `1a`. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56bcb/9)

Comment: @GarethD Your method is correct. Thank you. Write an answer I can accept it

Comment: @GarethD: thanks, added `alpha` in case he wants something stricter than `alnum`.

Comment: It's not about boosting your own rep. It's about helping other beginner developers on my level with php get this done right. @Konerak's answer doesn't work for what I'm looking to achieve. It does exactly the wrong method I posted on my question.

Comment: @jQuerybeast I have just edited this answer to show a method that will work for you. Ignore the method in my original comment `^1[:alnum:]`, it was me being an idiot.